# Adding Data to a Datagridview column by column in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to add records from two listboxes into a datagridview. The items from Listbox1 must fill the cells in the first column of the datagridview and the items from listbox2 must also fill the cells of the second column of the datagridview.

This is what I have been able to come up with after researching and working around codes.

```
  Listbox1.items.Add("Abeeku")
Listbox1.items.Add("Naana")
Listbox1.items.Add("Pokuaa")

Listbox2.items.Add("Arhin")
Listbox2.items.Add("Yaa")
Listbox2.items.Add("Kobina")

DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2
DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "Col 1"
DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "Col 2"

Dim str(Me.DataGridView1.ColumnCount) As String

str(Me.DataGridView1.Columns(0).Index) = ListBox1.Items(0)
DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, str)
str(Me.DataGridView1.Columns(0).Index) = ListBox1.Items(1)
DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, str)
str(Me.DataGridView1.Columns(0).Index) = ListBox1.Items(2)
DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, str)


str(Me.DataGridView1.Columns(0).Index) = ListBox2.Items(0)
DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, str)
str(Me.DataGridView1.Columns(0).Index) = ListBox2.Items(1)
DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, str)
str(Me.DataGridView1.Columns(0).Index) = ListBox2.Items(2)
DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, str)
```

The above fills the datagridview columns alright but it seems to repeat the first item of Listbox1 in proportion to the items in Listbox2 before it inserts the rest of the items in Listbox1.

Any work around would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
For i = 0 to 2

    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(Listbox1.Items(i), Listbox2.Items(i))

Next
```

Comment: Wow... Thanks @David Popovici. This is exactly what I have been looking to implement. Code so simple. I am very thankful.

Comment: Ok sir. Thanks once again.